# Data not showing on new page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, frontend

I have created a web service that has 2 methods, general and details. General shows basic data whereas the details provides further details on the selected object. I am finding difficulties in loading the new page with details showing.

These are the angular methods I've created.

```
var app = angular.module("myModule", .....);

var app = angular.module("myModule2", [])
                    .controller("myController2", function ($scope, $http) {

                        $scope.test = "DetailsScript";

                        //method to get booking by reference start
                        $scope.getReference = function (Reference) {

                            $http({
                                method: 'GET',
                                url: 'http://localhost:3466/MyWebService.asmx/DashboardDetail',
                                params: {
                                    Reference: Reference
                                }
                            }).then(function (response) {
                                $scope.booking = response.data
                            });
                        };
                        //method to get booking by reference end

                        //method to load page start
                        $scope.loadView = function (ref) {
                            var url = 'DetailsPage.html';
                            $scope.getReference(ref);
                            window.location(url);
                        };
                        //method to load page end
                    });

angular.module("CombineModule", ["myModule", "myModule2"]);
```

When I click the following buttin I cannot seem to get the details to go to the new page:

```
<input id="refBox" type="text" ng-model="Reference" ng-change="getReference(Reference)" />
            <br />
            <input type="button" ng-click="loadView(Reference)" />
```

The ng-click simply takes me to the new page without the new data loaded.

My web service gets called correctly and returns the correct `Context.Response.Write(javascriptserializer.Serialize(myObject));`

There may be two problem: The page is loaded and displayed before the data is returned as it is asynchronous, and if that is the case, why? as the loadView calls getReference which has the .then function?

P.s. I am new to angularjs.

Comment: Please show us your angular routes

Comment: I do not have angular routes.

Comment: check out stateprovider for angular and use that to move between states. if you need to share data between controllers checkout [this](https://gist.github.com/joeLloyd/563738e041f3c3d8b16b) Gist i made

Comment: In an angular application generally every "page/screen" need a route. I suggest you [Angular Ui Router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router)

Comment: "reference" object is not exposed to $scope. You can only access variables from that's on $scope from HTML.

Answer (score 2):

This is not how angular works. The general concept behind angular is that you

1. Load the page (application)
2. Load all data that should be shown on that page
3. Display the data on the view

So the issue with your approach is, that you are loading the data and then leave the application (by going to the DetailsPage.html). You would not do that.

If you want to show detail pages, you should have a look into ngRoute.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, there are a few issues with the example that you provided.

First, you are assigning two different modules to the same var in

```
var app = angular.module("myModule", ...
```

and

```
var app = angular.module("myModule2",...
```

That seems not to be critical in the given example, but might be an issue.

---

Second, you are defining what seems to application logic in the view logic. Even though angular don't enforce you to use the MVC pattern, be aware that Controllers should be the "bridge" between your view (HTML) and your application logic (Services). Therefore, you should implement the "getReference" method whithin a [service](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services).

Services are, as written in the Angular's guide, singletons and have application life-cycle, whereas Controllers have a view life-cycle, and they should handle application logic and/or communication with server(s). In other words, services exists while the application exists, and a controllers will be available while a view is loaded.

Again, this is not critical **as long as this is just a test and should definitly not going into production**. Also it's a pain to maintain

Be aware, that when I say "application logic" it's the logic that **can go to client**. Your product logic should be enforced by the server, but sometimes you want to replicate that in the client, that's where you use the services

---

Third, as many people told you to do, you should check on the [ngRoute](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute) module. It's a native module and, if I understood your problem correctly, will solve your problem and do what `loadView` suposed to do.

You'll have something like this:

```
var someModule = angular.module('someModule', ['ngRoute']);

someModule.config(["$routeProvider", function($routeProvider){
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: '/path/to/index.html',
    })
    .when('/some/route/:id/', {
        templateUrl: "/path/to/some/route.html",
        controller: "SomeController"
    })
    .when('/some/route/:id/details/', {
        templateUrl: "/path/to/some/route.html",
        controller: "SomeDetailsController"
    })
    .when('/another/route/', {
        templateUrl: "/path/to/another/route.html",
        controller: "AnotherController"
    });
}]);

someModule.controller('SomeController', ['$scope', '$routeParams', function($scope, $routeParams){
  //Using routeParams, you can get information from the route
  //For instance, if you want the get details from a book with id "abc123"
  //Then when the route '/some/route/abc123/' is accessed, 'abc123' will be available
  //through $routeParams
  $scope.id = $routeParams.id;
  //$scope.id = 'abc123'
}]);

someModule.controller('SomeDetailsController', ['$scope', function($scope){
  //do stuff
}]);

someModule.controller('AnotherController', ['$scope', function($scope){
  //do stuff
}]);
```

This way, as in `SomeController1`, you can get the id for the book and use a service to get from a server.

Note that when you go from `/some/route/abc123/` to, lets say, `/some/route/abc123/details/`, the controller of the first one (`SomeController`) is destroyed and the controller of the second (`SomeDetailsController`) will be created. That's want I meant by "view life-cycle" and that's the reason why you should implement the app logic in the service, for it will be available during this transition.

---

Hope it helps. Good Luck.

Comment: this is a fantastic overall of example of angular, thank you.